# How to change font for specific characters?

Tags: fonts, characters

I would like to use a font (e.g. ebgaramond) except for some characters (e.g. all digits) for which I would prefer another font (e.g. ebgaramond-math).
What is the easiest solution for in pure pdflatex? And with xelatex or lualatex?

Comment: I think you have to better clarify your dependencies, such as used Latex flavor (xetex, context, Latex, luatex).

Comment: Thanks, I specified it